# How to find corners given a set of points

Tags: shapes, geometry, points, corner-detection

Say I have  shapes represented by a set of points on the edges. [A hexagon and a circle, with the points defining them in green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxVge.png)

Some points may be collinear or continuous (as in the circle).

How can I write an algorithm detect the corners of the shapes?

In this case it should be that the corners of the hexagon are returned. However, if the shape has a smooth curve it should not return any corners

Thanks

Comment: Are these points ordered or unordered?

Comment: ordered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the points are ordered, you can compute the turning angle between vec{P(i-m),P(i)} and vec{P(i),P(i+m)} for each point P(i). If the turning angle is greater than a pre-defined threshold, then P(i) can be considered as a "corner point". You will have to experiment a bit to find out the proper value for m and the threshold.

Comment: Is there a formal definition of "turning angle"?